# Arrows out of a product

Tags: category-theory

I am stuck on something that might not be too important, but it nevertheless bothers me, as I don't grasp it.

I am self-studying Awodey's book and at the beginning of page 41, after products have been defined, he discusses the following.

Consider arrows out of the product, $g:A\times B \to Y$. Given any two generalized elements $f_1:X\to A$ and $f_2:X\to B$, we have an element $g\langle f_1,f_2\rangle: X \to Y$. Such arrows $g$ are not ``reducible'' to anything more basic.

He says that something useful is gained if a category as products, because of this. What does he mean with this? What does ``reducible'' mean? What does more basic mean?

To be fair, he does mention that he will return to this later in Chapter 6 (in the context of ``exponential'' $Y^B$), but as he puts it here, I assume it is something I should be able to grasp by reading the first 40 pages or so.

If it is an irrelevant/unimportant question or something that will be (indeed) clarified much later, please feel free to ignore my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Awodey used "reducible" in quotes as you have presented it here, then most likely the statement was intended as an informal statement and similarly with "basic".

The idea is to be contrasted with the following: given an arrow $h : C \to A\times B$, this is equivalent to a pair of arrows $h_1 : C \to A$ and $h_2 : C \to B$. (Indeed, this is exactly what the universal property of products states.) Therefore, if we had a bunch of expressions involving arrows that mapped *into* products, we could rewrite those expressions in terms of the more "basic" objects, $A$ and $B$, and arrows, $h_1$ and $h_2$. In other words, everything we could say about expressions involving arrows into products, could just as well be said without and thus we gain no "power"/"expressiveness" in that context.

On the other hand, given an arrow $g: A\times B \to C$, we can not "break down" an expression involving it into "simpler" expressions that don't involve the product, $A\times B$. Arrows like $g$ are the kinds of things that a category having products allows us to describe that we wouldn't have been able to describe otherwise. This is why in universal algebra or model theory we talk about the arity of function symbols, i.e. the number of arguments it has, but we don't feel any need to specify the number of "outputs" it has, and we are not limited by only considering function symbols with a single "output". If we were limited only to unary function symbols, though, that would be a dramatic limitation.